# How to deal with an UnboundLocalError?

Tags: python, django

so in my code here,

```
if ...:
    if form.is_valid():
                order_created = create_order(request,item)
                order_number = order_created.id
                if order_number:
                    ....

context = {'total':order_created.total}
```

when i run this i get the `unboundlocal error,local variable 'order_created' referenced before assignment`.I have looked around and `learnt` i actually cannot access a variable within a block out of that block. I also learnt that i should not use the `global statement`. 
How else can i access `order_created`,i could have declared it out of the if block but that does not validate the order.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although you didn't paste the whole view, I'm pretty sure that the error comes
from the fact that you don't account for when the form is *not* valid.

So when you use it on the `context` dictionary, the `order_created` has never 
been defined.

So you should do something like:

```
if form.is_valid():
    order_created = ....
else:
    order_created = None

context = {'total': order_created.total if order_created else None}
```

**EDIT:** 
Keep in mind though that this is not the proper way to handle forms in django.
I hope that you've read [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/#using-a-form-in-a-view). When the form is valid and you successfully
create an order, you *should* redirect the user to a different view.

Answer (score 2):

Python scoping is perhaps a little less block-oriented than in other structured languages, you can access that variable outside the block, as long as the code path actually went through that block. For example, this will cause an error:

```
b = False
if b:
    x = 5
print x
```

But this will not, even though x is accessed OUTSIDE the block:

```
b = True
if b:
    x = 5
print x
```

The trick is to set the variable to something before you enter the block:

```
order_created = None
if ...:
    if form.is_valid():
        order_created = create_order(request,item)
        order_number = order_created.id
        if order_number:
                ....
if order_created is not None:
    context = {'total':order_created.total}
else:
    context = ...
```